# Multiple bash scripts to execute at a time in a single command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, command

I have three bash scripts which will give output with options.

./script_1 list
./script_2 list
./script_3 list
./script_9 list

and these numbers differs with servers but the first word in every server is "script".

now I want to run all these scripts together with same option 'list'. I need something like ./script_* list ?? or a command with ls or awk or anything else..

Running the process in background is not fulfilling my solution as I appended it into another script.

Comment: Why would you think `ls` or `awk` would allow you run your scripts in parallel?

Comment: and why is running in the background not a solution? You can run in the background in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in ./script_*; do
    $i list
done
```

If this is not the use case you're seeking, you'll have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: @jeremysprofile : Note that, unless you do a `shopt -s nullglob`, this would produce an error message if no script_ files are present.